# How to convert this useEffect for a React class based component?

Tags: reactjs, class, use-effect

I have this useEffect, for refreshing the page once after loading, in my react functional component:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(reloadCount < 2) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('reloadCount', String(reloadCount + 1));
      window.location.reload();
    } else {
      sessionStorage.removeItem('reloadCount');
    }
  }, []);
```

but I also want to use it in a class component, how can I convert it for that ?

I tried like this but it doesn't work :

```
componentDidMount(){
        if(reloadCount < 2) {
          sessionStorage.setItem('reloadCount', String(reloadCount + 1));
          window.location.reload();
        } else {
          sessionStorage.removeItem('reloadCount');
        }
      }
```

it gives me `'reloadCount' is not defined`

Can this be converted for usage in a react class component ?

Comment: In your functional component, where is `reloadCount` defined? is it a state variable?

Comment: it is not defined somewhere else, that's all the code I need to use in my functional component

Comment: So, it's a global variable?

Comment: try this.reloadCount

Answer (score 0):

in class components you should use this.reloadCount